# Apply style for parent element when it is focused

Tags: html, css, styles

```
 **CSS**

    #child:focus > #parent {
    color: white;
    } 

    **HTML**
    <div id="parent">
        <div id="child">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is this the correct way to apply styles for parent when child is focused ?

Edit: My problem is I need to apply these styles for small devices. So I can't use Jquery. Thats why I am trying within media query in css.

Comment: what is jquery got to do will this seems like you want a css solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to add a `tabindex`  attribute to your divs, or they can never receive the focus.

I have also included the code to remove the CSS class from the parent when the child loses focus.

```js
$("#child").focusin(function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass("focused");
});
$("#child").blur(function() {
  $(this).parent().removeClass("focused");
});
```

```css
.focused {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent" tabindex="-1">
  Parent Top
  <div id="child" tabindex="-1">
    Child
  </div>
  Parent Bottom
</div>
```

Comment: This can not be done in pure CSS, until the `:has` selector is supported by all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use jQuery for this:

```
$('#child:focus').parent().addClass('your_class');
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS have not selector for select up level ... you need solve the your problem use JS

Answer (score 1):

For this particular need was `:focus-within` pseudoclass implemented in CSS. In your example following CSS would do what you try to accomplish. I added `tabindex` to `#child` to make the `div` focusable. It is not necessary for elements natively focusable (eg. links or form elements). However, it is not supported by IE and Edge. Edge will support it after planned [switch to Blink rendering engine](https://www.gsmarena.com/microsoft_switching_edge_over_to_chromium_bringing_it_to_windows_7_8_and_macos-news-34593.php).

See also this [CSS Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/focus-within/).

```css
#parent {
  padding: 0.25em;
   background-color: crimson;
}

#parent:focus-within {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
  <div id="parent">
      <h1>Parent</h1>
      <div id="child" tabindex="0">
        <p>Child (click me!)</p>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite simple using JQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
if ($(window).width() < 960) {
    $('.child input').on('focus', function(){
    $('.parent').css({
    'background-color': 'blue'
    });
 });
   $('.child input').on('blur', function(){
    $('.parent').css({
    'background-color': 'lightgrey'
    });
 }); 
}
 
});
```

```css
.parent {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 display: block;
 background: lightgrey;
}
input {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"><input type="text"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can specify if window width is smaller than a value, so you can apply that style in every screen you want. I edited my snippet :)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by [4th Level selecor](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational) pseudo-class that works the same as the [jQuery implementation](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/).

```
#parent:has(> #child) { /* styles to apply to the #parent */ }
```

but this is [not currently supported by browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has).

[why we don't have a parent selector](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-parent-selectors)